# Disable Controls on Access Forms on Load

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am trying to create a form that allows me to control Access for people inputting data. The idea is to have all the controls disabled when the form loads and when they select different topics various fields would be selected accordingly. I know the long-hand way on how to do this field by field but I was hoping to do this as a batch but everything I try fails.

This is what I currently have

```
Dim control As control
Dim formName As String
Dim fieldName As String
Dim fieldParse As String


strFormName = "frm_Outfalls_Profile_Events"
For Each control In Forms(strFormName)
fieldName = control.Name
fieldParse = Left(fieldName, 5)
If fieldParse = "event" Then
    Me.fieldName.Enabled = False
End If
Next
```

Comment: Try `control.Enabled = False`

Comment: @FunThomas That was one of the things I tried but in the drop down menu Enabled isn't one of the functions and it errors out. I get

Run-time error '438'

Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified version of your code which suspends errors to avoid cases where the `Enabled` property does not exist.

```
On Error Resume Next
For Each ctl In Forms.frm_Outfalls_Profile_Events.Controls
    ctl.Enabled = Not Left(ctl.Name, 5) = "event"
Next ctl
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you.
I think I was getting hung up in the part where the cases didnt have the enabled property

Comment: Good to hear. Keep in mind, if you're running this on the same form, you can replace `Forms.frm_Outfalls_Profile_Events` with `Me`.